# Font looks corrupted on a new install

Tags: fonts

Sorry, I'm completely new to Linux and have no idea what I'm doing.

I've installed Ubuntu on a *very* old laptop (Samsung P500), but it looks like all UI text is garbled and corrupted. None of the images or any other functionality seems to be broken, just text.

Edit: I should add the text in programs like Firefox appears to be fine. It's just the Ubuntu UI.

[image: Garbled text in Ubuntu.]